# How to eliminate pixel noises from mouse movements in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I was getting the moment when mouse stops while I was not controlling the remotely, but now I control the cursor remotely. Right now, I can not get the moment when mouse stops, because It never exactly stops, it is always moving a little bit. My idea is to add some offset pixels. For example 5 px, even the mouse moves around 5 px, It will say that mouse stopped.

This was the some part of the code to capture the moment mouse stops. It triggers a timer. I didn't put here the timer code.

```
 mouse = new MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
 mouse.MouseMove += (sd, args) =>
 {
      movingCount = 0;
      mouseLeft = args.X; //set the window.left to mouseLeft before showing it
      mouseTop = args.Y; //set the window.top to mouseTop before showing it
 };

 mouse.Enabled = true;
```

What are your ideas about getting the moment when mouse doesn't stop but moving around 5 px noise?

Comment: You could use the SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance/ SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance 
These values can be used to determine if a mouse move was large enough during a DragDrop to count as "moved". I am pretty sure this can be used for your environment as well. The advantage is that this value is hooked up in windows.

Comment: Thanks for your info, can you put some links or some example code how to do that ?Then I can figure out how to use it, because I'm new in this area :S ... Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

As requested in the comments here's an example:

You can use the System Parameters MinimumVerticalDragDistance and MinimumHorizontalDragDistance.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.minimumverticaldragdistance.aspx

They are originally used as a threshold in DragDrop Operations to detect if the drag is really beginning or if the user was only clicking and moving the mouse pointer a very small distance.

Here's how it could be used:

```
private Point _lastPosition;

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this);

  if (IsMovementBigEnough(_lastPosition, currentPosition))
  {
    // .. do stuff here 
  }

  _lastPosition = currentPosition;
}

public bool IsMovementBigEnough(Point previousMousePosition, Point currentPosition)
{
  return (Math.Abs(currentPosition.X - previousMousePosition.X) >= SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
       Math.Abs(currentPosition.Y - previousMousePosition.Y) >= SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance);
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the code...Now everything is confused. because, in my code, I was triggering a timer with " args in the code" when mouse stops, now I can not get it with your code, am I right ? probably, this code can not work...:S